# Swift 3 - Multi View Controller errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently, I am making a flashcards app for my mobile app design class. Here is my code for the SearchController.swift file

```
import UIKit
class SearchController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    var flashcard: Flashcard?
    let baseSearchURL = "https://google.com/search?q=apple developer"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let card = flashcard,
            let escapedURLString = searchURLString(baseSearchURL, term: card.term),
            let url = URL(string: escapedURLString) {
                webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

    fileprivate func searchURLString(_ base: String, term: String) -> String? {
        return "\(baseSearchURL) \(term)"
            .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    }
}
```

The line:

```
let escapedURLString = searchURLString(baseSearchURL, term: card.term)
```

gives an error saying

> "Missing argument label 'base:' in call"

The line:

```
return "\(baseSearchURL) \(term)"
```

gives an error saying

> "Static member 'init(stringInterpolationSegment:)' cannot be used on instance type of 'String'"

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Replace `baseSearchURL` with `base` in the `return` line.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning

```
 return "\(baseSearchURL) \(term)"
```

here you should return `base` instead of `baseSearchURL` like,

```
 return "\(base) \(term)"
```

missing argument error should be solve like,

```
  searchURLString(base: baseSearchURL, term: card.term)
```